# Rspec 2 - "rspec" command gives no outpu

Tags: rspec2

With Rspec 2 the "rspec"command is supposed to run the tests, replacing "spec" from previous versions. 
I tried running it on a new app and no tests were run (despite having a set of specs created). Regular rake spec works fine to run the tests so the issue is with the command

jack$ rspec

Finished in 0.00003 seconds
0 examples, 0 failures

Using Rails 3 
rspec-2.0.1

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to tell it where your specs are.  Try

```
rspec spec/
```